# Wordpress show sub navigation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have the default wordpress menu which displays sub navigation links on hover but I'm wanting to show the sub navigation only when the user clicks the parent link. You can see my menu here https://jsfiddle.net/foley13/83sk1p1x/

I have a little javascript that should do this but isn't working.

```
$(function(){
   //Hide all the sub menus
   $('.sub-menu').hide();

   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
      //Find the child ul and slideToggle
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle('fast');
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
   });
});
```

I don't know if CSS is preventing this working but I just want to remove the hover and just have click.

Answer (score 1):

You have troubles with li:has(ul). Just add class "dropdown" to these li, which have dropdown. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works for me, I turned on jQuery in jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/83sk1p1x/2/

```
(function(){
   //Hide all the sub menus

   $('li.menu-item-has-children').hover(function(){
    $('li.menu-item-has-children').children("ul.sub-menu").css({"display":"none"});
    return;
   });

   $("li.menu-item-has-children").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      //Find the child ul and slideToggle
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle('fast');
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
   });
})();
```

However, in WordPress (due to its issues with jquery's $) you will have to write the function this way:

```
(function($){ ...
  // code
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Script**

```
$(function(){
   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("hover");
   });
});
```

And in `css` you need to replace `:hover` with `.hover`
[Check working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83sk1p1x/3/)

Comment: That's great, I have bookmarked for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for your help but I managed to solve my issue by still having my original script:

```
$(function(){
   //Hide all the sub menus
   $('.sub-menu').hide();

   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
      //Find the child ul and slideToggle
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle('fast');
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
   });
});
```

but I removed the left: -999em; from the .sub-menu and .sub-menu ul and this resolved the hover issue